# Api Post always has user as null even though there is a logged in user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to have an api for my answers app.
When a post is created, the user is always set to null.
I am not sure of why that is.

How do I auto-add some fields to the saving object, like the authenticated user, user IP address?

Here is my serializer:

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserPublicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'is_staff',
            'photo_url'
        ]
class AnswerCreateUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserPublicSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = [
            'object_pk',
            'content_type',
            'answer',
            'user'
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['user']
```

And the api create view:

```
class AnswerCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Answer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnswerCreateUpdateSerializer
```

And the model is:

```
class AnswerAbstractModel(BaseAnswerAbstractModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'),
                             blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(class)s_answers",
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    answer = FroalaField()
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date/time submitted'), default=None, db_index=True)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(_('IP address'), unpack_ipv4=True, blank=True, null=True)


class Answer(AnswerAbstractModel):
    class Meta(AnswerAbstractModel.Meta):
        db_table = "answers"
```

I beg your pardon for my ignorance of the django world. I am trying hard to figure it out though.

That said, what should be the approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the **`perform_create()`** method of the **`AnswerCreateAPIView`** as below,

```
class AnswerCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Answer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnswerCreateUpdateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

---

### Update-1

> Why do you need to override?

#### Case-1

You set **`user`** as [**`read_only_field`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only) in your **`AnswerCreateUpdateSerializer`**. By doing so DRF serialzier won't fetch any input data from ***JSON payload even if the data present in it***

#### Case-2

If you unset the [**`read_only`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only) property, DRF will ask you to provide a **`dict`** like object for the **`user`** since you have a ***Nested serializer*** configuration.

#### The DRF way

If you want to save the ***logged-in user*** to the DB in DRF, you should set the **`user`** field as **`read_only`** and override appropriate methods and fetch the logged-in user from request object.

Comment: Funny thing is I have other apis set up almost in the same way but I didn't need to override stuff.  Can u share some light on why I need the override here? Is it because of the model? Thank you.

Comment: @LearnToday I have updated the answer. I hope it clarifies your doubts.